# Can't insert or update Activite entity on Trigger_name : execution of After update

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, case

I written a batch class on case to update the one field on case object. And i written a Trigger on case to update the field on **`Entitlement`** object. And Trigger is working fine. But when i run the batch class, i am getting this error:

> Can't insert or update Activite entity on Trigger_name : execution of After update.

And then i inactivated trigger then Batch class working fine. Please give me your suggestions???

Here I am giving my code:

```
global class batchCaseUpdate implements Database.Batchable < sObject > {
    BusinessHours bs = new BusinessHours();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // bs =  [SELECT Name,Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = 'Neazeland Working hours'];
        String query = 'SELECT Id,CreatedDate,Priority_Questions__c,Priority_Flag__c,Priority_Hours__c FROM Case WHERE Priority_Questions__c = true';
        // query += 'AND Status INCLUDES  // AND status != Saved
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < Case > scope) {
        bs = [SELECT Name, Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = 'Neazeland Working hours'];
        for (Case a: scope) {
            Datetime startDate = a.CreatedDate;
            Datetime endDate = system.now();
            // String id='01mN00000004DHT'; //New zealand Business Hours
            String id = bs.Id;
            System.debug('###Start date is' + startDate);
            System.debug('###end date is' + endDate);
            Long timeValue = BusinessHours.diff(id, startDate, endDate);
            decimal hoursVal = timeValue / (60 * 60 * 1000);
            System.debug('###Time is>>' + timeValue);
            System.debug('###hours Value is>>' + hoursVal);
            a.Priority_Hours__c = hoursVal;
            if (hoursVal >= 24) {
                a.Priority_Flag__c = true;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

---

**Trigger:**

```
trigger trgCaseStatus on Case(After insert, After Update) {
    //List<Entitlement> lst_Entitlemet = new List<Entitlement>();
    //Public Boolean Moreinfo ;
    for (Case o_case: trigger.new) {

    }
    Case cse = [Select EntitlementId, Entitlement.RemainingCases, Contact.Email, CaseNumber, Status, Priority_Questions__c from Case where Id =: trigger.newmap.keyset()];
    Entitlement o_Entitle = [Select Id, RemainingCases, CasesperEntitlement from Entitlement where Id =: cse.EntitlementId];
    Integer casenum = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Reject'
        and EntitlementId =: cse.EntitlementID
    ];
    Integer casenums = [SELECT count() FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId != '012N00000004x9Z'
        and EntitlementId =: cse.EntitlementID
    ];
    // && cse.Priority_Questions__c == false
    if (cse.Status == 'Reject') {
        o_Entitle.RemainingCases = o_Entitle.CasesperEntitlement - casenum - casenums;
        Update o_Entitle;
    }
}
```

Please give me Suggestions how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by quickly scanning your code, I could find an issue: your trigger is not bulkified. That is, it only works when inserting/updating one record at a time.

This line:

```
Case cse = [Select EntitlementId, Entitlement.RemainingCases, Contact.Email, CaseNumber, Status, Priority_Questions__c from Case where Id =: trigger.newmap.keyset()];
```

will fail when you're updating more than one record at a time, because you cannot assign a list of 2 cases to a single `Case` variable. This is very easy to test with some anonymous Apex.

There might be other issues ontop of that.

I would suggest writing good unit tests for your trigger, including the bulk case, to make sure it's doing what you want, then you can see whether it works or whether something needs fixing in your batch.

I wrote [an article about how to test your triggers](http://blog.mkorman.uk/testing-apex-triggers/), which you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mkorman.... Yeah... Just i edited in trigger, Now i taken List. Now i solved my issue..